# Web-scraping on Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to download the response of POST-request on https://www.avast.com/hackcheck/ site as JSON file. But my request to the site return an error 400. My code is:

```
URL = 'https://identityprotection.avast.com/v1/web/query/site-breaches/unauthorized-data'
params = {'emailAddresses':['xxx@x.ru']}
headers = {'Vaar-Version': '0'}

req = requests.post(URL, params, headers)
req
```

The request on the site works correctly
[The request on the site works correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yX2tJ.png)

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should include all the other parameters in your request header also (not just the `Vaar-Version`). See screenshot below of the full POST variables:

[image]

**Note:** Even then it may not necessarily work

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in your header:

```
headers: {          
         Accept : "application/json",          
     }
```

Also, keep in mind where you put equals (=) and where you put semicolons.